# Typeahead.js - Special characters are returned as "&#230;" etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead.js

I have a strange problem with Twitters Typeahead. If a value and name is:

`indlæg`

It will display correctly in the suggestion link, but as soon as you mark it, and the value is pasted into the input box, the `æ` is gone, and then looks like this:

`Indl&#230;g`

I have verified the source is UTF-8 and everything else on the page also. My only thought is, that it has something to do with the typeahead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging, I found the solution to the problem, which was so simple. I found out, that the problem that nothing to do with the typeahead.js module.

I simply had to decode the entities using: [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode)

My bad!

Comment: Decoding will not make it xss venerable?